Flooding in crawl space from heavy rain
The past few days in the Pacific Northwest saw some heavy rain, which flooded the crawl space under our house. I can't even open the crawl space door to get a pump in to address the flooding immediately. I've never noticed our crawl space flooded before, which seems about a few feet tall. How much of a problem is having a crawl space flooded and will it drain on its own or is this an emergency? I'm going to address some preventative measures in the future, though, to try and minimize this in the future.

why can't you open the crawl space door?

Are there foundation vents you can stick a suction hose through to start to get some water moving?

how deep is the water? ... how many feet is seems about a few feet tall

@jsotola, the water seems to have swollen the wood, so the door is stuck. But we also recently had the vent door replaced and added concrete frame and honestly they made it too tight (the contractor had to remake the door already).
I'm spitballing the height of the water because I can't measure it but our crawl space is about two to three feet tall and there's maybe a foot between the water surface level and where the bottom of the house is

@AloysiusDefenestrate we recently replaced our house vents for rodent control so there's only one place where we can remove the vent and it's the crawl space access door, which is stuck.

To answer your question, you don’t want standing water in there for more than a week or so. Maybe try a bit more force to get the door open… depending on the door, it might be irreparable because of the moisture anyway, so trashing it doesn’t set you back.
